# Pushing Android library to jCenter javadoc error

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, jcenter

I'm trying to upload a library to jCenter following this tutorial:

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en

The problem comes when I do ./gradlew install . When is generating the javadoc, I get a lot of errors like this one:

```
/src/main/java/communicationManager/datareceiver/DeviceShimmer.java:7: error: package com.shimmerresearch.android does not exist
import com.shimmerresearch.android.Shimmer;
```

Basically, I have inside my Android Studio module a few jar's libraries that I need to use, and it doesn't find them when is creating the javadoc. I've tried adding the following to my module build.gradle, but no luck:

```
task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    options.links("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/");
    options.linksOffline "http://d.android.com/reference","${android.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference"
    exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
    exclude '**/R.java'
    failOnError = false
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
}

artifacts {
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocsJar
}
```

This is how my project build.gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.exampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'libs/commons-math-2.2.jar'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile project(':mymodule')
}
```

And this is how my module build.gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

ext {
    bintrayRepo = 'maven'
    bintrayName = 'name'

    publishedGroupId = 'com.name'
    libraryName = 'name'
    artifact = 'name'

    libraryDescription = 'description'

    siteUrl = 'https://github.com/...'
    gitUrl = 'https://github.com/...'

    libraryVersion = '2.0.1'

    developerId = '...'
    developerName = '...'
    developerEmail = '...'

    licenseName = 'GPL-3.0'
    licenseUrl = 'http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html'
    allLicenses = ["GPL-3.0"]
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'libs/commons-math-2.2.jar'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:12.0'
    compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:3.1.3'
    compile files('libs/ShimmerAndroidIntstrumentDriver_v2.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/ShimmerDriver_v2.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/wekaSTRIPPED.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}

apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle'
apply from: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/bintrayv1.gradle'


task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
    options.links("http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/");
    options.linksOffline "http://d.android.com/reference","${android.sdkDirectory}/docs/reference"
    exclude '**/BuildConfig.java'
    exclude '**/R.java'
    failOnError = false
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}

task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.sourceFiles
}

artifacts {
    archives androidSourcesJar
    archives androidJavadocsJar
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The issue I had was having two or more java jdk versions on my machine or having an outdated java jdk while having the latest jre.

Removing all the jdks and having the most up to date jdk and jre fixed my issue.